# Implementing a Bootstrap template inside Meteor app

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor, less

I am trying to implement one of the commercially sold Bootstrap templates in my application, but I am getting several issues as shown below. The template just works fine outside of my Meteor app. So I am confused why I am seeing all of those errors? Do I have to use Meteor packages (Ex. Meteor bootstrap, JS packages) and substitute template packages with those of Meteor packages? Is there is anything I am missing here while implementing this template in my app? Thanks

```
  client/views/assets/lib/bootstrap-datepicker/less/datepicker.less:13:2: Less compiler error: .border-radius is undefined
   client/views/assets/lib/bootstrap-datepicker/less/datepicker3.less:103:16: Less compiler error: variable @gray-lighter is undefined
   client/views/assets/less/bootstrap/custom.less:12:2: Less compiler error: .border-radius is undefined
   client/views/assets/less/pages/chat.less:5:9: Less compiler error: .reset_ul is undefined
   client/views/assets/less/pages/gallery.less:4:5: Less compiler error: .reset_ul is undefined
   client/views/assets/less/pages/invoices.less:6:16: Less compiler error: variable @link-color is undefined
   client/views/assets/less/pages/login.less:25:16: Less compiler error: variable @screen-sm-max is undefined
   client/views/assets/less/pages/mailbox.less:15:13: Less compiler error: .border-radius is undefined
   client/views/assets/less/pages/search.less:4:5: Less compiler error: .reset_ul is undefined
   client/views/assets/less/pages/user_list.less:4:5: Less compiler error: .reset_ul is undefined
   client/views/assets/less/pages/user_profile.less:7:5: Less compiler error: .border-radius is undefined
   client/views/assets/less/partials/breadcrumbs.less:12:3: Less compiler error: .reset_ul is undefined
   client/views/assets/less/partials/header.less:11:3: Less compiler error: .transition is undefined
   client/views/assets/less/partials/main_menu.less:10:22: Less compiler error: variable @side_menu_expanded_width is undefined
   client/views/assets/less/plugins/c3.less:29:12: Less compiler error: variable @white is undefined
   client/views/assets/less/plugins/datatables.less:134:16: Less compiler error: variable @white is undefined
   client/views/assets/less/plugins/datepicker.less:12:4: Less compiler error: .border-radius is undefined
   client/views/assets/less/plugins/daterangepicker.less:6:13: Less compiler error: .border-radius is undefined
   client/views/assets/less/plugins/easy-pie-chart.less:28:9: Less compiler error: .custom_font is undefined
   client/views/assets/less/plugins/fullcalendar.less:4:5: Less compiler error: .custom_font is undefined
   client/views/assets/less/plugins/gmaps.less:5:5: Less compiler error: .box-shadow is undefined
   client/views/assets/less/plugins/gridforms.less:10:13: Less compiler error: .custom_font is undefined
   client/views/assets/less/plugins/jvectormap.less:8:9: Less compiler error: variable @white is undefined
   client/views/assets/less/plugins/listnav.less:5:5: Less compiler error: .cf is undefined
   client/views/assets/less/plugins/notifications.less:3:5: Less compiler error: .opacity is undefined
   client/views/assets/less/plugins/parsley.less:6:23: Less compiler error: variable @brand-danger is undefined
   client/views/assets/less/plugins/plupload.less:7:17: Less compiler error: variable @theme-color is undefined
   client/views/assets/less/plugins/rangeSlider.less:5:2: Less compiler error: .border-radius is undefined
   client/views/assets/less/plugins/select2.less:9:3: Less compiler error: .box-shadow is undefined
   client/views/assets/less/plugins/switchery.less:4:20: Less compiler error: variable @white is undefined
   client/views/assets/less/plugins/wizard.less:5:3: Less compiler error: .cf is undefined
   client/views/assets/less/css_animations.less:6:40: Less compiler error: variable @easeInOutQuart is undefined
   client/views/assets/less/demo.less:6:5: Less compiler error: .custom_font is undefined
   client/views/assets/less/media_queries.less:3:8: Less compiler error: variable @screen-md-max is undefined
   client/views/assets/less/style.less:31:15: Less compiler error: variable @main-bg is undefined
   client/views/assets/less/style_switcher.less:16:27: Less compiler error: variable @easeInCubic is undefined
   client/views/assets/less/themes.less:20:21: Less compiler error: variable @theme-secondary-color is undefined
   client/views/assets/lib/parsley/src/wrap/append.js:1:17: Unexpected token )
   client/views/assets/lib/parsley/src/wrap/prepend.js:19:3: Unexpected end of input
   client/views/assets/lib/c3/src/head.js:6:3: Unexpected end of input
   client/views/assets/lib/c3/src/tail.js:11:1: Unexpected token }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try having a look at this: https://github.com/rune-ks/meteor-boilerplate

As stated in the readme, I forked it from Differential and updated it. Ofcourse, you can delete/remove/add anything you'd like, so it works for you. I just set it up, so that it works for me.

To answer why Meteor is throwing errors, I'm pretty sure it's because Bootstrap's less files use a lot of `@import`'s and to do that with Meteor, the less files have to be called `<somefile>.import.less`. Otherwise it gets all confused when it tries to compile all the less files in to one css file.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by removing the rules where an error is thrown. I would also say it is an issue with not including the the files were the rules are defined. For example @include variables, or what ever the file is called where the variable "link-color" is defined. Eg. $link-color: pink;
It will always work outside of meteor as a static page will run on complied css. Link Color may be undefined but the browser will just ignor the rule you are trying to give link color and probably default to the bootstrap standard rule for that element